# How to set time as PM in bootstrap datetimepicker by default?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

I want to set time as PM in the code but by default, it's showing  AM

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                        icons:
                        {
                            next: 'fa fa-angle-right',
                            previous: 'fa fa-angle-left'
                        },
                        format: "DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm:ss ",
                        extraFormats: ['DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm:ss'],
                        defaultDate: moment(dateNow).hours(8).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0)

                    });
```

Comment: 8 is 8 AM. If you want 8 PM, use 20 for your default hours value

Comment: I used 20 but still there in AM in datetimepicker

Comment: hello I just need to change AM into Pm